# How can I round numbers in SharePoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am working on a workflow for a financial organization. To calculate a commission in one currency, I divide the amount in another currency by the exchange rate, which I then convert to text, and put in a word document. However, often end up with rather long numbers like 1.23233434. How can I round this number before it enters the contract? I want to round to two decimals.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the ROUND function?

For example: =ROUND(number,2)

See more information [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/round-function-HA001161059.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I know this function from Excel, but how do insert it in my workflow in SharePoint Designer (2010)?

Comment: I have found evidence suggesting that you cannot the same formula's from SharePoint in Workflows. See following link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/dc77e2b5-57e1-4281-adb3-8bbe1b44bd73
What u indeed could do is just let your workflow as it is and create an extra calculated column within SharePoint that rounds up your results which u can use for your word document, just as @lem.mallari suggests.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the answer of Dafalgor, you don't have to use SharePoint designer to get the rounded number. You can just create a calculated column referencing another column which stores your long number and just use the calculated column for your word document.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and to avoid calculated columns I used the basic provided arithmetic calc functions in workflow. For example, to get a file size in KB without a ton of decimals I did:

```
var FileSize = ItemFileSize + 512
var temp = FileSize % 1024
FileSize = FileSize - temp //(now I have filesize at the closest multiple of 1024)
FileSize = FileSize / 1024
```

Notice the trick to add 512 is to round to closest, instead of simply truncate

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Workflow Actions Pack](https://plumsail.com/workflow-actions-pack/) and [Evaluate expression workflow action](https://plumsail.com/docs/workflow-actions-pack/Actions/SharePoint%20Utils.html#evaluate-expression). It allows to evaluate complex formulas including Round and many other.

Note: it is paid third party solution. I'm a developer of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's 'Do Calculation' action in SharePoint Designer and there's 'mod' operator available. If you have a variable Double1=2.75, you Do Calculation: Double1 mod 1. The result is 0.75. Than you just do calculation again: Double1 minus result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple logic to round any Number N to d number of decimal places in SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013.

For Example:
The number N is 984.268975 which you want to round up to 2 decimal places. Expected answer is 984.27.

**Follow below steps in designer workflow**

N = 984.268975 , d = 2

1. Do calculation -> N multipliedby 10(d+1), where d is number of decimal places required in rounding. Set N to the result of this calculation.

   so, N = N * 1000 = 984268.975
2. Do calculation -> N mod 1, which will give you decimal part in a temp variable.

   so, temp = 0.975
3. Do calculation -> N minus temp, this will remove decimal part. Set N to the result of this calculation.

   So, N = 984268
4. Do calculation -> N dividedby 10. Set N to the result of this calculation.

   So, N = 98426.8
5. Do calculation -> N mod 1, which will again give you decimal part in a temp variable.

   So, temp = 0.8
6. Now put this if-else condition

   If temp >= 0.5

   ```
   Set variable IsRoundingNeedsIncrementToLastDigit to true
   ```

   else

   ```
   Set variable IsRoundingNeedsIncrementToLastDigit to false
   ```
7. Do calculation -> N minus temp, this will remove decimal part. Set N to the result of this calculation.

   So, N = 98426
8. Do calculation -> N dividedby 10*d. Set N to the result of this calculation.

   So, N = N/100 = 984.26
9. Now put this if condition

   If IsRoundingNeedsIncrementToLastDigit is true

   ```
     Do calculation -> N add (1/(10*d)), this will increment the last decimal digit.

     So, N = N + 1/100 = N + 0.01  

     N = 984.27, which is our expected answer.
   ```

Thanks. This can be applied to rounding to any number of decimal places.