# Workflow calculations

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer

In sharepoint designer workflow, I need to do multiply and divide decimal number and the result should also be a decimal number. As I noticed, workflow rounds the decimal numbers.

Example:

- I get - `1000*1.1=1000 ; 1000/1,1=1000`
- I need - `1000*1.1=1100 ; 1000/1,1=909.09`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create calculated column to do the calculation. Later use those calculated column in workflow.

The similar question asked before:  [How can I round numbers in SharePoint designer?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66796/how-can-i-round-numbers-in-sharepoint-designer/66824)